# Why did Israeli sportsmen keep their hats on during their national anthem?

Tags: clothing, song-poetry, politics-government, kavod, state-of-israel

Last year I was at the international softball tournament and I noticed that players from Israel took off their baseball caps during the other teams anthems (as is common courtesy), but kept them during their own national anthem.

I have wondered about it for a long time.

- Were the sportsman obligated to remove their hats to observe the custom of the others?
- Did they keep their own hats out of a personal choice, or a religious obligation?

I'm concerned that this question might be inappropriate for this site or unanswerable at all, but I am really curious about it.

Comment: Your question maybe is being downvoted because it's being read péjoratively. I presume they kept the hats because the way of their nationality understands that covering the head is important.  Their time - their rules.

Comment: I am sorry, if it's being read that way, I didn't want to be offensive in any way. I am not a native English speaker, so it's probably misunderstanding. I did some research about head covering generally and I think I see the point, so I will vote for deletion as this question is probably off-topic on this site. Thanks for response.

Comment: Your question itself is about Jewish life, so it's reasonable it may be on-topic.  I won't speculate about why the downvote.

Comment: I think it's interesting, but, sadly, off-topic.

Comment: @SethJ, see what you think of [the version before NewAlexandria's edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/20618/revisions).

Comment: @SethJ, wouldn't "is this a Judaism thing?" be very much on topic?

Comment: @msh210, I did not see the original. I think that makes all the difference.

Comment: In the first bullet, does that mean _religiously_ obligated, or by some convention/rule of international competition?

Comment: @msh210 - any idea on the above?

Comment: @SethJ It is cultural convention, probably with Christian origins. There are some occasions (e.g. anthems, minute of silence, in the church, or in the buildings generaly) where are you supposed to take off the hat. The tournament was in the Europe (Czech), so I guess that answer to question 1 is "yes". Question 2 is more complicated to me. But I see that the customs about wearing a hats are completely different, so "their time, their rules" make sense to me.

Comment: @jpesout, ok, but my question is on the question - are you asking about whether the Israelis were "obligated" because of some international sportman's convention to follow the local customs, or are you asking whether the Israelis were "obligated" by their own competitive rules to follow the local customs, or are you asking whether _Judaism_ "obligated" them to follow the local custom?