# Should a man remove his head covering during the national anthem?

Tags: song-poetry, chutz-laaretz, kippa-yarmulka, politics-government

The custom in the United States is to remove head coverings (and place them over the heart) during the recitation of the national anthem. Is there any Jewish reason for a man to, or not to, follow this practice?

[related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20618/why-did-israeli-sportsmen-keep-their-hats-on-during-their-national-anthem)

Comment: "Is there any reason for a man to" -- you mean, a Judaism-based reason? Because there's certainly a *reason*: out of respect, the same reason gentiles do it.

Comment: @msh210 edit for clarity. Not sure why the tag politics

Comment: It's [tag:politics-government], which I thought relevant. By all means edit it out if you disagree with that. Come to think of it, I may disagree with it, myself. `:-)`

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but Rav Ruderman told my father that when the students of Slobodka Yeshiva were sent to see a doctor they were instructed by the Alter, Rav Nosson Tzvi Finkel that upon encountering the doctor they should remove even their Kappalach (Yarlmukas) out of respect.

Comment: Removing hats during the National Anthem in the United States is done out of respect. We wear yarmulkes in respect of Hashem. Should we then remove our yarmulkes, which are for showing respect to HKB''H to show respect to the nation, Chas v'Shalom?